# add 1 to css selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add dynamically +1 to css selector each time function happens so it would select next question each time.

```
var questionCount = 2;
var previousQuestion = 1;

function start(){
document.getElementById("question" + questionCount).className = "question_box";
document.getElementById("question" + previousQuestion).className = "question_box disabled_gone";
$('#question' + previousQuestion).animate({height: '0', margin:'0',padding:'0'});
var questionCount = questionCount + 1;
var previousQuestion = previousQuestion + 1;
}
```

It works when I add first variables at the beginning of function but it will set variables to 2 and 1 once i run function again.

Comment: just do `.className = "question_box" + questionCount ;`

Comment: It will add +1 to class name. I need to add +1 do ID in css selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var questionCount = questionCount + 1;
var previousQuestion = previousQuestion + 1;
```

Should be

```
questionCount++;
previousQuestion++;

// OR

questionCount = questionCount + 1;
previousQuestion = previousQuestion + 1;
```

I believe you are creating a new variable in the function scope, which is deleted once the function is over, meaning when it is run again it calls from the global scope, namely 2 & 1

Comment: Ah thanks, I still get confused about local and global variables sometimes.

Comment: Happens to all of us mate. Gl with this c: